# Switching keyboard layout and shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-layout, shortcuts

I often switch from French to US keyboard and the usual key shortcut for application keep on being as if it was French.

Is it possible that the application (Kile is an open application with which I have problem) follows the shortcut of the US keyboard when I'm using US keyboard layout and French when I'm in French ?

Example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (select all) becomes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> (quit), so if I'm using US keyboard and do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all the application closes interpreting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.... A bit annoying.

My question IS NOT about "how to add a shortcut for switching keyboard layout".

Comment: Are you using Kile in Unity or under KDE? And is French set as the system language?

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear possible to get Kile (or any KDE app) to behave the way that you want.

Gtk apps, such as Gedit, do behave the way you want. The keyboard shortcuts change according to the selected keyboard. They work this way whether under Unity or KDE.

KDE apps, in contrast, do not change the keyboard shortcuts when you change the keyboard layout. Rather, they will keep the shortcuts aligned with the system language setting. They work this way whether under KDE or Unity. I could not find any setting or configuration method in KDE to change this behavior.